# imageMagick mogrify module not found

Tags: php, imagemagick, mogrify

I'm experiencing problem with mogrify. When I run it from command line works like charm when from php I get this error.

```
"mogrify: unable to open module file `/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.2.8/modules-Q16/coders/orig.la': No such file or directory."
```

Strangely enough on other box the file is missing as well but my script works.
I'm doing simple thing injecting modified iptc that I  extracted with convert.
Any clues how to get it working? Install additional package?

the problematic machine config:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 04/17/08 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2006 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

the working one

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.9-0 2010-02-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Comment: What operating system is this? Try deinstalling and reinstalling IM.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageMagick 6.2.8 version you have installed on your problematic machine probably doesn't contain the mogrify library, or it isn't correctly installed. Try reinstalling imagick and make the library version match the one you have installed on the working one.

Comment: well the thing is the mogrify works when executed from command line I updated the package from centos 5.3 repo and noticed that convert output has changed. Iptc fields were no longer printed one item per line. So I compiled 6.5.9-0 from sources. Was much faster than googling for the error. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Well the problem could be that the config on the problematic machine showed that the cmd was using /usr/share as the module directory, while the error in PHP showed it was trying to use /usr/lib64/, where the file wasn't present.